# Background Color behind Heading <h1> with padding with line break

Tags: html, css

I want to give a background color to `<h1>` and wanted it to extend with the text and with equal paddings on left and right.

It seems ok on single line but when I break a line the padding messed up.

Here's my code:

```css
h1 span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sai Bongaro</span></h1>
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum <br>Doler Sai Bongaro</span></h1>
```

[image]

I want the space after lipsum and before doler in the second `<h1>`

And it shouldn't look like a box...

So it look like this:

[image]

Comment: using `display:inline-block` ( as mentioned in the answers below ) solves your question ( the way you asked it ) . so if that's not what you want, be more specific

Comment: I thought the answer with inline-block would do what you wanted, but you said it didn't. Could you be more specific on the outcome you expect?

Comment: No its not ... my question is clear that I wanted space not make it a box...

Comment: An image of the desired result would be helpful

Comment: Thanks @j08691 ... Added the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should change the HTML like this :

let me know if it helps

```css
h1  span{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display:inline-block; /*optional */
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum Doler Sai Bongaro</span></h1>
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum </span><br /><span>Doler Sai Bongaro</span></h1>
```

Comment: That's logical... Is there any other way?

Comment: i couldn't think of any other way that doesn't involve changing the html. glad i could help. cheers :D

Comment: Thanks though ... better than nothing 

Answer (score 1):

You could use `box-decoration-break` which is [currently supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak) in Firefox and supported with prefix in Chrome, Safari and Opera. That way you only need one `<span>` element.

```css
h1  span{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum <br />Doler Sai Bongaro</span></h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add display: inline-block to span inside h1

```
h1 span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Then write that man in your question, be clear about what you ask.